# How to get json encode data into dropdown field in php?

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#region").change(function(){
            region = $(this).val()
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"region":region},
                url:"get-city.php",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    //$("#city").html(data);
                    //$("#state").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<select name="region"  id="region" >
    <option value="">Select Region</option>
    <?php 
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `region`");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
        {
    ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['heading_text']; ?>"><?php echo $row['heading_text']; ?></option>
    <?php 
        } 
    ?>
</select>
<select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="">Select Region State</option>
</select>
<select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="">Select Region City</option>
</select>
```

get-city.php

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(0);
    include('dbase.php');
    $region = $_POST['region'];
    $sql = "select * from region_data where heading_text='".$region."'";
    $results = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
    {
        $data[] = array(
                            'state' => $rows['state'],
                            'city' => $rows['name']
                        );
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

In this code I have created simple dropdown one is for `region` where I change its `value` by `id` as you can see in jquery code. Now, As you can see in `get-city.php` file I have encode data via `json_encode` function which work fine. But problem is I am not able to show data in `state` and `city` drop down in php. My json_encode data look like:

```
[{"state":"","city":"delhi"},{"state":"","city":"agra"},{"state":"","city":"varanasi"},{"state":"","city":"haridwar"},{"state":"","city":"dharamshala"},{"state":"","city":"srinagar"},{"state":"","city":"mussoorie"},{"state":"","city":"amritsar"},{"state":"","city":"shimla"},{"state":"","city":"kullu manali"},{"state":"","city":"assam"},{"state":"","city":"meghalaya"},{"state":"","city":"arunachal pradesh"},{"state":"","city":"manipur"},{"state":"","city":"nagaland"},{"state":"","city":"J AND K"},{"state":"38","city":"Saharanpur"}]
```

So, How can I get value in dropdown? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get back a JavaScript object from a JSON string, you are looking for `JSON.parse()`.
I did not got exactly how you want to display data, but as far as I understand you are looking for a way to populate the dropdowns, so I will show you only for the city part...for all the other dropdowns the flow is the same.

Assuming you have all the cities in the `cities` variable after the AJAX call (and after the JSON.parse call if needed):

```
let cities = [{"state":"","city":"delhi"},{"state":"","city":"agra"},{"state":"","city":"varanasi"},{"state":"","city":"haridwar"},{"state":"","city":"dharamshala"},{"state":"","city":"srinagar"},{"state":"","city":"mussoorie"},{"state":"","city":"amritsar"},{"state":"","city":"shimla"},{"state":"","city":"kullu manali"},{"state":"","city":"assam"},{"state":"","city":"meghalaya"},{"state":"","city":"arunachal pradesh"},{"state":"","city":"manipur"},{"state":"","city":"nagaland"},{"state":"","city":"J AND K"},{"state":"38","city":"Saharanpur"}];

cities.map(function(item, index) {
  // let's build an <option> element
  const city = jQuery("<option>", {value: item.city, text: item.city})
  // let's add the <option> element to the right <select>
  jQuery("#city").append(city);
});
```

Comment: your code is working @Lorenzo S but what about `state` I have also state data that will be show in state drop down

Comment: @omkara can you please tell me the logic to update the state dropdown? Which value should be inside the select? So I can update my answer with the relevant code!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `parseJSON` in jQuery to decode the JSON data and then `append()` the option values to city and state `select` tags.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#region").change(function(){
            region = $(this).val()
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"region":region},
                url:"get-city.php",
                success:function(data){
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(obj, function() {
                        $("#city").append('<option value="'+this['city']+'">'+this['city']+'</option>');
                        $("#state").append('<option value="'+this['state']+'">'+this['state']+'</option>');
                    });
                    //$("#city").html(data);
                    //$("#state").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wasn't working because I wrote `get-region.php` instead of `get-city.php` as you are using. Now, it should work.

Comment: still blank dropdown list @Verma Jr.

Comment: Which one? The state or the city?

Comment: both state and city

Comment: Must be some error with with your `get-city.php` because it's working fine on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the solution. You can search more for **dependent dropdown**

use value.city and vvalue.state as you want, or key as option value , its upto you, i just showed how you get values

```
  $.ajax({
        url:"get-city.php",
        data:{"region":region},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $('select[name="city"]').empty();
            $.each( JSON.parse(data), function(key, value) { // or use data without  JSON.parse(data) 
                $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="'+ value.state +'">'+ value.city +'</option>');
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I use your code but it revert object object in city drop down @AhmedSunny

Comment: try now @omkara

Comment: i think will work without json.parse, just need value.state and value.city

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `success` section:

```
success:function(data){
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="'+ data[i].city +'">'+ data[i].city +'</option>');
        }
    }
```